# setting alternating values to be bold

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I  am trying to manipulate some data from a google spreadsheet into a google doc.  I am using the code below to pull a cell range and then put the results into my doc.

```
var sh11 = sh0.getRange('P2:P10').getValues();
var announcement3 = ""; for (var i = 0; i <= sh11.length - 1; i++) { announcement3 += sh11[i]+"\n"; }
```

Is there a way to set the results from every other cell to be **bold**?  I tried the straight forward way of setting the cells themselves to be **bold** but that didn't work.  I also tried to define it by using

```
textelement.setBold
```

But that didn't work either.  I had a look at [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?csw=1#setFontWeight(String)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?csw=1#setFontWeight%28String%29) but I think I am missing something.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Paul

Comment: You do not show in your question the part of your code that puts the values into the document. The issue is probably there.

Comment: Hi.  Everything is there, but this line `copyBody.replaceText('keyAnnouncement3', announcement3);` which puts it into my google doc template.

Answer (score 1):

If you trying to set text bold of a spreadsheet cell, then you have to use '**setFontWeight("bold")**'. Ex.:

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").setFontWeight("bold");

If you trying to set text bold of a document, then you have to use '**setBold(true)**'. Ex.:

var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().editAsText();
doc.appendText("text to insert").setBold(true);

Comment: Hi, what I am trying to do is a combination of both.  If I could set cells P3, P5, P7, P9, and P11 to be **bold** and then transfer them to my google doc with the formatting preserved, that would be perfect.  Currently, I am trying using this code `var sh11 = sh0.getRange('P2:P10').getValues();
    var sh11 = sh0
    var cell = sh11.getRange("P3").cell.setFontWeight("bold");`

However, when it is transferred to the google doc, it doesn’t retain the formatting and I get an error when I run the script.  I get this “TypeError: Cannot call method "setFontWeight" of undefined”

Comment: Unfortunately range format can only be copied between spreadsheets. What you could do is to control it yourself, like the example bellow: 
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:A10")
  var values = range.getValues();
  var fontBold = range.getFontWeights();
  
  
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById("your_doc_id").getBody()
  for (var x = 0; x < values.length; x++){
    var isBold = (fontBold[x] == "bold")
    doc.appendParagraph(values[x]).setBold(isBold)
  }

Comment: Hi.  I can't quite wrap my head around what you'v written.  Would it be possible for you to break it down for me?  If I understand it correctly, you are asking it to get the values in the range of the active spreadsheet, and set that to bold.  After that I think you are calling the template and trying to put the values in.  Do I have that right?

Comment: No, no.. What I have written before is to get the font style from each cell in the range(from the spreadsheet), and one by one set it on the document. See the example in this spreadsheet I have prepared for you: [spreadsheet example] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DdH9OoZW1-kwL1iSYBGFE7j5clJfzjhId-ommICrEIs/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Okay.  Thank you for the clarification.  I definitely had the wrong idea there. How does this integrate with the script I am currently using?  This is that part of it `var announcement3 = ""; for (var i = 1; i <= 10 - sh22; i++) { announcement3 += sh11[i]+"\n"; }`  Announcement 3 is what is replaced within the google doc.